# Bassistance validation with attributes. What's the syntax?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

According to the documentation - such as it is - you can specify validation that requires a parameter of an input element by using an attribute.  It says this is the recommended method.  Like this:

```
<input type="password" minlength="6" maxlength="50"/>
```

Okay, that's easy.  Now how do you specify (for example) a range using an html attribute?

```
<input type="number" range="[5, 50]"/>
```

No, that doesn't work.  Neither does no brackets, curly braces, curly braces and brackets or any combination thereof.  But this works in a completely unexpected way:

```
<input type="number" range="53"/>
```

- it spits out the error message "number must be between 5 and 3"

Can someone please show me the proper syntax for this?

NOTE:  This is an exemplar.  I realize I could solve this particular problem by using

```
<input type="number" min="5" max="50"/>
```

I'm looking for a more general answer regarding how to construct a complex validation rule using the jquery-validate attributes API.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's another example.  How do you do this using the "preferred" attribute syntax?

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        rt: {
          required: function(element) {
            return $("#age").val() < 13;
          }  
        }
    }
});
```

The following does not work:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age"/>
    <input type="text" id="rt" name="rt" required="function(element) { return $('#age').val() < 13;}"/>

    <input type="text" id="tabcatcher"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Play with the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GKNZF/

Comment: Not getting your point. What's wrong with `<input type="number" min="5" max="50"/>`? Why are you looking for somwthing else?

Comment: Added another example to the question

Comment: Maybe a better restatement of the question is - can anyone state the syntax to be used for those validation rules that can be invoked via attributes, and also state which validation rules can NOT be invoked via attributes?  I will take that statement and submit it as a documentation patch to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue/bug in the plugin, as reported **[here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/112)**. Basically, the plugin is considering `53` as an array of two digits, with `5` as the mininum value, and `3` as the maximum.

To fix it, you need to apply the following patch:

```
// Patch by Chris Tierney (CF Webtools 7/13/2011)
// Issue logged at https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/112
$.each(['rangelength', 'range'], function() {
    if (typeof rules[this] == 'string') {
        rules[this] = rules[this].split(",");
    }
    if (rules[this]) {
        rules[this] = [Number(rules[this][0]), Number(rules[this][1])];
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay - I see that this is also fixed in a pull request for implementing html5 data attributes that will land shortly.  However this does not answer the broader question of "how to construct a complex validation rule using the jquery-validate attributes API."

Answer (score 3):

In the more general case, there is NO documentation regarding which validations can be invoked by adding a class, which can be invoked by adding an attribute and a parameter/expression/function, and which CANNOT be invoked via an attribute.  From the code, here is a list of validations that can be invoked by adding their name to the class list:

required
email
url
date
dateISO
number
digits
creditcard

The validations that I know can be invoked by an attribute:

min
max
minlength
maxlength
equalTo

Unknown.  There is no documentation of syntax required to make these work, nor is there documentation saying that they don't work:

required with callback
required with expression
remote

Does not work due to longstanding bugs:

range
rangelength